# phpexcel date is reading wrong format

Tags: php, phpexcel

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this but none of them actually has helped.

I'm having a cell in my excel file that I have to read.

[image: Cell Date in Excel]

and the format in the excel file is like below [image: Date Format In Excel]

In my php code I have it in a function that gets the sheet name and cell to read the cell .

```
$cellDate = $xls->getSheetByName($sheet)->getCell($cell)->getValue();
```

**I've also tried this with getFormattedValue() and got same result**

I then get the format with this

```
$format = $xls->getSheetByName($sheet)->getCell($cell)->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

when I echo this out in PHP it shows the date as

```
13/4/2015
```

and for the format it shows

```
mm-dd-yyyy
```

where it show as dd-mm-yyyy

I now need to get Y-m-d format of these I've tried using all the available functions in PHPExcel but it's still the result is not correct.

I can't hard code the format because there are multiple cells with multiple formats and I need this to understand by itself

I've tried using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('A1')
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2 );
```

I really need this and I've already wasted 1 week on it.

Is there anyway to tell PHPEXCEL to parse whatever date is in the cell to Y-m-d format ?

**UPDATE**

As I was reading through the comments I went back and checked the function I wrote, I found that one of the cells [even] that it's formatted in Excel ,it's parsing a wrong format which in that case was a General Format;

I then got the value of getValue() and getFormattedValue() and compared these two if they are not the same that means it's formatted correctly and i can use PHPExcel to get dates from it.

BUT , (There is always a but). Thanks to Microsoft and its excel I'm still not able to differ 1st Feb 2016 and 2nd Of January ! which forever remains the question.

My only recommendation is to never trust excel formats !

Comment: `Thanks to Microsoft and its excel`.... strictly speaking, it isn't Microsoft or Excel at fault here; it's users who have entered dates as string values rather than letting MS Excel use its own internal serialized date/time value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `getValue()` and `getFormattedValue()` both return a string containing `13/4/2015` then your cell content isn't a MS Excel date/time value but a standard string, and trying to apply a date format mask to a string won't achieve anything. PHPExcel's date formatting functions will only work if the cell content really is an MS Excel serialized datetime value, not simply  string.

You'll have to use standard PHP functions like DateTime::createFromFormat() to convert the string value to a datetime object, and can then use the `format()` method to convert it to whatever format you want.

Alternatively, try passing the value to the PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel() to convert it to an MS Excel serialized timestamp; and setting that as the cell value, and then you can set a format mask and use `getFormattedValue()`.

Comment: The issue I have is that i'm reading more than 1000 (Locked Xls) files and somehow , for some dates i'm getting a date like 2014-10-13 as 10/13/14 , 13-Oct-2014 , 10,13,2014. i think once i wrote a function about 800 lines to be able to understand which format is it and still unable to figure it out . i would face problem when i have dates like 01/02/2016 where i have no idea what format it is !

Comment: I've also tried using PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel() , it's either i don't know how to use it or it doesn't work

Comment: LIke I said, they're not MS Excel dates, they're simply strings if you're getting the same value returned by both `getValue()` and `getFormattedValue()`, and PHPExcel can't really help you if it is simply a string.... if these were MSS Excel date values, then getValue() would return an integer or float value, not a string

Comment: Using `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel()` will convert that "string" to that Excel integer/float if the string can be interpreted as a date, but can't easily differentiate between 01/02/2016 as 1st February or 2nd January, so can return incorrect values

Comment: PHPToExcel returns Thu, 14 Jan 1904

Comment: That will be because the cell value isn't an MS Excel date, it's a string.... standard PHP string rules apply, it tries to convert the string to a numeric value so that it can treat it as an MS Excel timestamp, and gets 13.... spreadsheet is set to use the Mac 1904 calendar, which has a base date of 1st January 1904 as day 1.... 13 days from day 1 is 14th January 1904

Comment: I repeat, these are not dates, they are strings that a human being interprets as dates, but nothing more than strings to a computer.... use standard PHP date functions such as DateTime::createFromFormat() to convert them to PHP DateTime objects, and then you can format them however you wish; but PHPExcel cannot give you some kind of magic wand here

Answer (score 1):

```
$objReader= PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');  // For excel 2007 
//Set to read only
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);        
//Load excel file
$objPHPExcel=$objReader->load(FCPATH.'assets/uploads/yourFolder/'.$file_name);        
$totalrows=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();   //Count Numbe of rows avalable in excel          
$objWorksheet=$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);                
//loop from first data untill last data
for($i=2;$i<=$totalrows;$i++)
{   
$field0= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue(); //Excel Column 1
$field1 = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue(); //Excel Column 2
$field2= $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getFormattedValue(); //Excel Column 3
$date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($field2); //unix value
$field2= gmdate("Y-m-d", $date); //you can echo this value
}
```